# Moment format string not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am trying the absolute most basic moment test and it's not working at all.

I did the following:

```
npm install moment
```

then in an app.js I did the following:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var testDate = new Date();
console.log(moment(testDate).format('yyyy'));
```

Which should print a 4 digit year. Instead it prints

> yyyy

on the console.  why is it not formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `YYYY` instead of `yyyy`.

According to the [moment format docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) the valid formats for year are `YY` (example output `"15"`) and `YYYY` (example output `"2015"`).

Characters that are not recognised as format tokens are included as literals.

Comment: that did it.  I thought perhaps it was something more sinister because for some reason the IDE (intellij) i'm using recognizes all other node modules except moment